# How to get the heading of an alert in selenium webdriver using java?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I am able to fetch the content of an alert but need to fetch the Heading of alert.

Comment: Would it be possible for you to add the HTML content and the thing you have tried?

Answer (score 0):

If the alert is of windows then we can get the heading of that alert by using the autoit tool. To do this, download [autoit](https://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/downloads/), create the following script and compile it to get an `.exe` of the script

```
WinWaitActive('Name of your alert')
$heading= WinGetHandle('Name of your alert')
MsgBox(0,"Hello",$heading,0,0)
```

In your java code add the following line

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("C:\\Users\\user.abu\\Desktop\\fileUpload1.exe");
```

where `fileUpload` is name of your `.exe` script

Comment: is this answer about selenium webdriver?